# coherence of inverses in 2-groupoids

Tags: category-theory, higher-category-theory, groupoids

Given a 2-groupoid $G$, two objects $a,b$, and two 1-morphisms $f,g:a\rightarrow b$ and a 2-morphism $\alpha : f \rightarrow g$, is it the case that

1. there always exists a 2-morphism $\beta : f^{-1} \rightarrow g^{-1}$?  Denote the operation that sends $\alpha$ to $\beta$ by $\texttt{flip}$.
2. is it true that $\texttt{flip} \circ -^{-1} = -^{-1} \circ \texttt{flip}$ ?
3. what is $\texttt{flip}$ usually called?

My guess is that this is true.  However, I have scoured many sources (including many many pages over at the nLab), and I have not been able to find out if this is true.  Perhaps this is only visible at level $3$, which is why this is not pointed out in anything about 2-groupoids?

Comment: This is basically the question of whether we want our (strict) 2-groupoids to be 2-categories with the *property* that all 1- and 2-morphisms happen to be invertible, in which case there's no reason for your flip to exist, or with the *structure* of an inversion endofunctor, whose action on 2-morphisms would be your flip. It does seem that the most natural examples have a functorial inverse, but I don't see it in people's definitions.

Comment: Yes, that does seem to be an excellent rephrasing of the question.  This question (in either guise) seems very natural, so I am rather surprised that all I've gotten is a comment and nothing else.

Comment: Yeah, me too. I'm adding a category theory tag in case that'll draw more attention.

Comment: It seems to me that your operation is the composite of 2-cell inversion and 1-cell inversion.

Comment: @ZhenLin Yes, exactly.  The question is, do these operations always commute?

Comment: @ZhenLin and Jacques, all this is easily settled if inversion of 1-morphisms is functorial since functors preserve inverses. This falls out of a definition of a 2-groupoid as a groupoid internal to groupoids, but doesn't seem to be implied by a definition as a 2-category in which 1- and 2-morphisms happen to be invertible. No?

Comment: 1-cell inversion acts on 2-cells. In fact, [the natural operation](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/mate) sends a 2-cell $f \Rightarrow g$ to a 2-cell $g^{-1} \Rightarrow f^{-1}$.

Comment: Right, 1-cell inversion acts on 2-cells in that way -- which is why I asked about the existence of a different morphism, which is not *guaranteed* to exist.  I have a bicategory which is also a 2-groupoid which also has this operation on it, but I can't seem to find anything like that in the literature.